# How to check if new JSON file is available?

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, ios, jakarta-ee

I am building a mobile application that get all the information from a Java backend. The data is available through REST in JSON format. How would you manage to discover on the mobile device if the JSON is new or not? I was thinking of having one really simple JSON format file with only a timestamp that the mobile device checked each time to compare to what already stored...but it doesn't seems to be a good solution, at least I think. So are there other ways to do this? I am developing both the backend Java server application and the mobile device app (iOS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HTTP Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) including the [HTTP ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag). Here's an [example in Java](http://www.infoq.com/articles/etags).

```
If-Modified-Since   
Allows a 304 Not Modified to be returned if content is unchanged    

If-None-Match   
Allows a 304 Not Modified to be returned if content is unchanged
```