# Check if a remote JSON is newer than the local one without download the entire file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, http

I'm creating a Phonegap app that check if a local JSON is up to date comparing it with the last Remote version of it. If the remote version is newer than the local the program will update the local JSON.

To avoid bandwith waste I would like to do the version check without downloading the whole remote data. Just checking the headers... I guess...
Looking for a solution I found that some people talk about "HTTP ETag header" like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669999/how-to-check-if-new-json-file-is-available#8670036)

Does somebody know How could I implement something like that in pure Javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your server sends the correct response type of

`304 - Not modified` you can check for an update with something like this

```
function hasUpdate(url, callback)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
              // Data is new -- maybe do another request and grab a copy?
            } else  if (this.status === 304) {
              // Data is not modified
            } else {
              // Something else happened.
            }

        }
    };
    http.send();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy! Tell me if I'm wrong please. As I understand this will work for files that have not never been modified after their creation. So with this process I can't know if my local file is older than the remote one, because of the lack of comparation between the two versions.
Thank you!

Comment: That becomes a server-side issue and what headers your server-side code pays attention to.